# Classify E-commerce URLs into predefined classes

Tags: classification, nlp, text-classification, regex

How can I classify an E-commerce URL Page into the following categories,

1. Cart
2. Payment
3. Product Page
4. Checkout

How can I achieve this with the url and page title in my hand? I have tried multiple ways but nothing seemed solid. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information for a comprehensive answer, but I will try to assist you. You can try to hard code it without using any machine learning algorithms. Try looking at specific parts, letters or numbers in the URL that provide information that can tell you what category it is. What about page titles? Do they provide any information? You can manually write a small "decision tree" if the URL and titles provide you with any information.

If the URL-s and titles do not help you, you have to do a bit more work. You can use `beautifulsoup` to webscrape more data from the website. Maybe you will find something useful in the metadata. If the titles and URL-s do not determine the class, you will certainly find something you can scrape that will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Nemo_the_scientist! I have looked into web scraping as well but I wanted to know if I can work alone with URLs and Page titles as well. Pattern matching using regex and the decision trees helped me for now but I guess using this information I can scale up later by using some ML algorithm.